# create-react-app, installation error ("command not working properly")

Tags: reactjs, installation, command, create-react-app, project

I tried lot of time install the react project using  `npx create-react-app my-app` command. but I couldn't install react project. I had come below error. How to fixed this issue ?

[image]

```
Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

npm ERR! code ERR_SOCKET_TIMEOUT
npm ERR! errno ERR_SOCKET_TIMEOUT
npm ERR! network Invalid response body while trying to fetch https://registry.npmjs.org/postcss-minify-selectors: Socket timeout
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\Asanka Gamage\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-07-21T16_09_09_965Z-debug-0.log

Aborting installation.
npm install --no-audit --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-scripts cra-template has failed.

Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting abc-company/ from C:\Users\Asanka Gamage
Done.
```

I check my internet connection (there is no issue)
I reinstall the NodeJS

Comment: Are you at work or school, somewhere that has a proxy or firewall?

Comment: school, No I used proxy and firewall. Already have  default network setting.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a command like this, It seems that you are behind a firewall or proxy.

```
npm --proxy http://proxy-server:8080/ install {package-name}
```